# How could I get just one result from i18n table? (CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, multilingual

I query all row from a table and I get all row at all languages...

**For example:**
GalleryCategoriesController.php

```
<?php
class GalleryCategoriesController extends AppController
    {
    function index()
        {
        $galleryCategories = $this->GalleryCategory->find('all');
        print_r($galleryCategories);
        $this->set('galleryCategories', $galleryCategories);
        }
    }
?>
```

GalleryCategory.php (model)

```
<?php
class GalleryCategory extends AppModel
    {
    public $tablePrefix = 'ef_';
    var $name = 'GalleryCategory';

    public $actsAs = array('Translate' => array(
            'title' => 'titleTranslation',
            'title_sub' => 'titleSubTranslation',
            'description' => 'descriptionTranslation'
            )
        );
    }
?>
```

result:

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
        [GalleryCategory] => Array 
            (
            [id] => 1
            [gallery_category_id] => 0
            [title] => Test title
            [title_sub] => Test subtitle
            [description] => Test description
            [status] => 2
            [locale] => hun
            )
         [titleTranslation] => Array
            (
            [0] => Array
                (
                [id] => 65
                [locale] => hun
                [model] => GalleryCategory
                [foreign_key] => 1
                [field] => title
                [content] => Test title hungarian
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                [id] => 80 
                [locale] => eng 
                [model] => GalleryCategory 
                [foreign_key] => 1 
                [field] => title 
                [content] => Test title english
                ) 
            )
         [titleSubTranslation] => Array 
            ( 
            [0] => Array 
                ( 
                [id] => 66 
                [locale] => hun 
                [model] => GalleryCategory 
                [foreign_key] => 1 
                [field] => title_sub 
                [content] => Test subtitle hungarian
                ) 
            [1] => Array 
                ( 
                [id] => 81 
                [locale] => eng 
                [model] => GalleryCategory 
                [foreign_key] => 1 
                [field] => title_sub 
                [content] => Test subtitle english
                ) 
            ) 
         [descriptionTranslation] => Array 
            ( 
            [0] => Array 
                ( 
                [id] => 67 
                [locale] => hun 
                [model] => GalleryCategory 
                [foreign_key] => 1 
                [field] => description 
                [content] => Test description hungarian
                )
            [1] => Array 
                ( 
                [id] => 82 
                [locale] => eng 
                [model] => GalleryCategory 
                [foreign_key] => 1 
                [field] => description 
                [content] => Test description english
                ) 
            ) 
         ) 
     )
```

How could I get only the hungarian translation? Because If I have six languages in the website, and I query anything, I get it on six languages... It is terrible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model definition has to be changed according to [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html#defining-the-fields):
Try something like:

```
<?php
class GalleryCategory extends AppModel
    {
    public $tablePrefix = 'ef_';
    var $name = 'GalleryCategory';

    public $actsAs = array('Translate' => array(
            'title', 'title_sub', 'description'
            )
        );
    }
?>
```

Of course you also need to select the locale with:

```
$this->GalleryCategory->locale = <hun|eng>
```

in your Controller action.

Comment: Thank You! It's working!

But, I use this:
`<?php
class LanguageController extends AppController
 {
 public function change($lang = 'hun')
  {
  if (in_array($lang, array('hun', 'eng')) === true)
   {
   $this->Session->write('Config.language', $lang);
   }
  $this->redirect(Controller::referer());
  die;
  }
 }
?>`

So, there was no need for:
`$this->GalleryCategory->locale = <hun|eng>`